# How to calculate a multi-variable formula from a table of data

Tags: statistics

I have a table of several independent variables that I need to calculate a formula from to generate the dependent variable. Though trial I have come up with a value for the dependent variable. 
For example, I have a table like this:

```
x1 | x2 | x3 || z(value found by experiment)
-------------------
1  | 2  | 3  || 10
3  | 4  | 5  || 14
2  | 3  | 3  || 15
1  | 2  | 7  || 9
```

now I want a formula such that:

```
f(x1,x2,x3) = z
```

Now how do I go through and get the value? Can you point me to some resources?

I feel like I should remember this from my school days, but I dont.

**Also:** Do you know any tools that will do this for me? I have excel, but I cannot figure out how to do regression with more than one variable.

Comment: I'd suggest looking for a simpler class of formula first, perhaps ax + by + cz + d = value, and using regression analysis, as Louis RH suggests, to find values of a, b, c, and d that fit your data. With four unknowns and four data points, you'll probably find an exact fit; you may want to generate more data to evaluate whether a linear function v = f(x,y,z) is a good model for your experiment.

Comment: Excel actually have the tool, as an add-in. which version of excel do you have so that I can show you where to find it?

Answer (score 6):

You are talking about [regression analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis). If the relationship is linear, then it is [multiple linear regression](http://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Multiple_linear_regression) (more than one independent variables, one dependent variable, linearrelationship) See the links for further info

**Edits:** To do this analysis with Excel 2007: You must first enable the Analysis ToolPak in Office logo (top left) > Excel Options > Add-Ins > Manage (dropdown menu: Excel Add-Ins) > Go > Check Analysis ToolPak > Ok

Then you can choose Analysis > Regression in the Data ribbon where you can specify multiple columns as your input range. You can find a guide [here](http://www.jeremymiles.co.uk/regressionbook/extras/appendix2/excel/) about more details to use the regression tools, it's for an older version of excel but the regression tool is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to use VBA, not complicated Regression method. You can do it with **multiple variables and get multiple results**.

Table(sheet1):

```
x1 is cell A1 in VBA sheet1.cells(1,1)
x2 is cell B1 in VBA sheet1.cells(1,2)
x3 is cell C1 in VBA sheet1.cells(1,3)
z is cell D1 in VBA sheet1.cells(1,4)
```

Calculations are on 2nd sheet(sheet2);

```
cell A1 = x1 (variable; input for formulas)
cell A2 = x2 (variable; input for formulas)
cell A3 = x3 (variable; input for formulas)
cell A4 = z1 (result)
```

Create Button and type code in VBA

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

'rowCount is numbers of rows in your table(list1)
for m = 0 to rowCount-1

     'set table data to calculations
     'set x1
     sheet2.Cells(1, 1) = sheet1.Cells(2 + m, 1)
     'set x2
     sheet2.Cells(1, 2) = sheet1.Cells(2 + m, 2)
     'set x3
     sheet2.Cells(1, 3) = sheet1.Cells(2 + m, 3)

     'get z
     sheet1.Cells(2 + m, 4) = sheet2.Cells(1, 4)

next m
End Sub
```